# Unable to configure proxy for Terraform with AWS provider

Tags: proxy, terraform-provider-aws

We are running Terraform v12.20 to provision infrastructure in AWS. We have installed Terraform on an EC2 instance and we need to have our corporate proxy configured in order to communicate with services outside our network. We have sts.amazonaws.com configured in our no_proxy. Terraform is not respecting the proxy configured in the environment variables because of which it's timing out trying to connect to sts.amazonaws.com. Here is the proxy that's configured on the instance.

```
http_proxy=XXX:YYY
https_proxy=XXX:YYY
HTTPS_PROXY=XXX:YYY
no_proxy=sts.amazonaws.com
NO_PROXY=sts.amazonaws.com
HTTP_PROXY=XXX:YYY
```

This is the error I'm getting when trying to run terraform init.

```
error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: RequestError: send request failed. caused by: Post https://sts.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp 54.239.21.217:443: i/o timeout
```

Can someone help me configure proxy with terraform?

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably silly but do you need to use the ```set``` command before these? Have you verified that the envs are present in the environment (you could probably just test with a source if it's bash)

Comment: This is linux not windows

Comment: question stands, have you verified that the envs are actually present?

Comment: Yes, I did env | grep proxy on the instance and it has the below values.   http_proxy=XXX:YYY
https_proxy=XXX:YYY
HTTPS_PROXY=XXX:YYY
no_proxy=sts.amazonaws.com
NO_PROXY=sts.amazonaws.com
HTTP_PROXY=XXX:YYY

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's doing exactly what you told it to. You say your environment requires an HTTP proxy to access the internet but you've put sts.amazonaws.com into no_proxy, which is the environment variable for sites you explicitly do not wish to proxy - hence terraform is not using your proxy to go to sts.amazonaws.com and it is failing. Simply put, remove sts.amazonaws.com from your no_proxy variable.